# golang concurrency sync issue

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I am facing a synchronization issue when using goroutines. My program outputs unpredictable results. I checked the docu and for unbuffered channels there is no way to check if all msgs have been processed. I simplified the issue to this little demo code that still demonstrates the problem. Clearly this is not an issue with Golang but with my code. Obviously I am not using the right concurrency pattern.

Question is how to resolve this. If possible I would neither want to close the channel nor stop the hive goroutine. It think it would be great if I could assume that once all bee goroutines are finished that hive is done for now, too (that is what I tried by using wg.Wait()).

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)



func main() {
    count := int64(0)
    c := make(chan int64)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // bees
    for i:=0; i<5000;i++{
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(in chan int64) {
            defer wg.Done()
            time.Sleep(100)
            in <- 2
        }(c)
    }

    // hive
    go func() {
        for out := range c {
            count += out
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    // bang! but why?
    fmt.Println(count)  
}

// every now and again the program prints out before it is finished
// $ go run pattern1.go
// 10000
// $ go run pattern1.go
// 9998
// $ go run pattern1.go
// 9998
// $ go run pattern1.go
// 10000
// $ go run pattern1.go
// 10000
// $ go run pattern1.go
// 9998
```

Comment: You have a data race in your code, please run your code with the '-race' flag (go run/build -race). This will print out information about data races as they occure.

Comment: You can't tell if the "hive" loop has processed all values from `c` without closing `c`, or inserting another counter and synchronization primitive. If all goroutines are done, then what's the point of not closing the channel?

Comment: The -race flag must be after run but before the filename. Anything after the filename gets passed to your process, but -race is a compiler flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never waiting for the "hive" loop to finish, so sometimes you print the `count` value before it's complete.

It's easiest to use the WaitGroup to signal when to close the channel, and block `main` on the for range loop:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}()

for out := range c {
    count += out
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/jK24dtG2je